# UIPickerView doesn't appear

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

In a ViewController call by **push**, I try to programmatically display a ComboBox. This combobox implement UIPickerView delegate protocol and add a .xib file.

When i run the app, i can see my combobox on the screen, but when i click on it, nothing append. Normally the pickerview will be displayed.

What i don't understand, is in another viewcontroller call **modal** it works fine

```
//
//  ComboBox.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ComboBox : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    UIPickerView* pickerView;
    IBOutlet UITextField* textField;
    NSMutableArray *dataArray;
}

-(void) setComboData:(NSMutableArray*) data; //set the picker view items
-(void) setPlaceholder:(NSString*) label;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString* selectedText; //the UITextField text
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField* textField; //the UITextField

@end

//
//  ComboBox.m
//


#import "ComboBox.h"

@implementation ComboBox
@synthesize selectedText;
@synthesize textField;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    return [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


//-- UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
    return 1;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    textField.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:row];
    selectedText = textField.text;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [dataArray count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [dataArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

//-- ComboBox


-(void) setComboData:(NSMutableArray*) data
{
    dataArray = data;    
}

-(void) setPlaceholder:(NSString *)label
{
    textField.placeholder = label;
}

-(void)doneClicked:(id) sender
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder]; //hides the pickerView
}


- (IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender {

    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.delegate = self;

    UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [toolbar sizeToFit];

    //to make the done button aligned to the right
    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpaceLeft = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];


    UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self
                                                                  action:@selector(doneClicked:)];


    [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpaceLeft, doneButton, nil]];

    //custom input view
    textField.inputView = pickerView;
    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;  
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)aTextField
{
    [self showPicker:aTextField];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

the viewdidload of my viewcontroller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray* ServeurArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [ServeurArray addObject:@"1"];
    [ServeurArray addObject:@"2"];
    [ServeurArray addObject:@"3"];

    comboServeur = [[ComboBox alloc] init];
    [comboServeur setComboData:ServeurArray];  //Assign the array to ComboBox
    comboServeur.view.frame = CGRectMake(95, 220, 130, 31);  //ComboBox location and size (x,y,width,height)

    [self.view addSubview:comboServeur.view];
}
```

thx for your answers

Comment: picker delegate methods are calling or not once check with break points.

Comment: the method showPicker which is connect to the UITextField isn't call when i clic on

Comment: @Nagasaki: Can you please improve your question?

Comment: My question is why the combox works in a modal VC and why it doesn't in a push VC?

Comment: how did you add pickerView? programatically or in xib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i try to use this combo class in my viewcontroller, i try all the solution you give to me, but nothing work, so the solution is to implement all the combo class code directly in my viewcontroller, and now it works, but it's a little bit uggly...

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are targeting iOS 5.0 and above. Since you are adding a view of a viewController to another viewController you can use the childViewController introduced in iOS 5.0.

Modify your viewDidLoad method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        ComboBox *comboServeur = [[ComboBox alloc]initWithNibName:@"ComboBoxController" bundle:nil];
        [comboServeur setComboData:@[@"1",@"2",@"3"]];

        comboServeur.view.frame = CGRectMake(50.0f, 200.0f, 220.0f, 31.0f);

        [self.view addSubview:comboServeur.view];
        [self addChildViewController:comboServeur];
        [comboServeur didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    }
```

Few steps to check

1. Make the view of the `ComboBox` viewController freeform with maskType `UIViewAutoresizingNone`.
2. Check the textField and delegate of textField is connected

[Demo project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/DemoContainerView.zip)

Comment: I will try that, but what do you mean by check delegate of textField is connected

Comment: @Nagasaki If you are implementing the UITextFieldDelegate, you can either connect it by IB or by code. That's what I meant.

Comment: @Nagasaki Did you test the demo project that I provided, if it is not working make sure that the view of the ComboBox is not automatically resized smaller than textField.

Comment: I didn't test it, but like i say the combobox work fine in a ViewController which it calls modal and doesn't work in another wich i call by push segue... I will try to uncheck autoresize of the view, i will tell you asap.

Comment: @Nagasaki You never mentioned about Push Segue. If you are using a viewController like a view, you need some more steps to get it work. You were using the ComboBox like UIView.

Comment: I mentione it, it's my first sentence in my question. Do you have a solution for it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29181/discussion-between-anupdas-and-nagasaki)

Comment: Sorry i can't... the proxy in my entreprise doesn't allow it ;(

Comment: You aren't doing an Push, you are just presenting a viewController, in which you are adding another viewController's view as subView. I think you haven't tried the demo project that I send to you?

Comment: I have tried the demo project, but crash at execution :( do you think if I replace ComboBox : UIViewController by ComboBox : UIView and associate combobox class to the view contain in the uiviewcontroller instead of the uiviewcontroller it will work?

Comment: @Nagasaki Your approach is correct, a controller is something which binds your view and data. If you are going to use this same combox in many places. This method is good. Can you let me know where the app is crashing. I couldn't reproduce the crash.

Comment: It crash when set the frame size, i use the last version of Xcode, maybe it's not compatible. I have ARC message in main loop when executing

Comment: @Nagasaki I made that project with XCode 4.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

I forget the specifics but I remember having the same problem but the thing for me was that I needed to link it to delegate or datasource or something? I'm not 100% sure since it's been quite a while but make sure when you have it on your view you link it to your picker reference + the other thing that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ComboBox` class isn't set as a delegate for the `UITextField`, so `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` will never be called.

Comment: @interface ComboBox : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate>
Yes, it is.